# Flask. App context and access to db.session a new thread. Application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an application on Flask + sqlalchemy.
And I need to delete the object from the database with a delay.
For this I wrote a class with a timer.

```
from threading import Timer
from ..extensions import db
# db = SQLAlchemy()

class Remover(object):
    """docstring for Remover"""
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(Remover, self).__init__()
        self.obj = obj
        self.t = Timer(10, self.remove)
        self.t.start()

    def remove(self):
        try:
            db.session.delete(self.obj)
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception, e:
            raise e

    def cancel(self):
        self.t.cancel()

u = User().query.first()
Remover(u)
```

But the timer is started in a new thread. Perhaps that's why I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1080, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/egregors/pythonProject/RSys/rSystem/admin/views.py", line 638, in remove
    raise e
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no
application bound to current context
```

Did anyone know how you properly implement such a class?
How to work with threads and application context?

Thanks

Comment: Is the use of a separate thread a requirement or a side-effect of using `threading.Timer`? If it's just a side effect you could just use `time.sleep` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Please read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/, then try:

```
with app.app_context():
    db.session.delete(self.obj)
    db.session.commit()
```